# Making an integration between two system secure using web services

Tags: json, web-services, api, security

I have two applications one is a business process management (BPM) & the other is a document management system (DMS) , both systems exposes web services to enable integration with other systems. Both system provide a master login username and password to provide  JSON API Authentication. for example to start a process ("process1") inside the BPM ; the DMS can send the following API call

```
/jw/web/json/workflow/process/start/process1?master_username=BPMadmin&master_password=982716171717&loginAS=currentusername
```

and same apply for calling DMS web services.

[image]

The limitation in this security approach is that i am unable to call any of the DMS or the BPM web services using JavaScript and consume the returned JSON using javaScript, since if i follow the javaScript approach i will be exposing the master_username & master_password to the end users and they can manually modify the LoginAs parameter to other usernames and perform actions they are not authorized to do.

so my questions are:-

1. Can i make the web service calls secure using JavaScript?
2. second question what other security approaches i can follow to make the web services calls secure using javaScript? baring in mind that i can modify the webs service security to other approaches rather than using master login username and password, but this might require more time and effort from my side?

Thanks in advance for any help
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all JS is client side and does not include any special security/magic/irreversible functions, like browser aided crypto engine, high grate SPRNG for key generation and so forth. So long story short anything you do with js is not secure it can be obfuscated but it will be NOT SECURE. That is the point you already made. Another more approach is to use your server as 'proxy'. So lets say You are designing an JS aided gui and show some documents ro so, then you make an AJAX request to your app server (not BPM nor DMS) and it acts as proxy that will do the authentication against DMS and call WS and then return the result back to your JS :) So your setup would look like JS (session)-> App (ws auth)-> DMS -> App (sesion)-> JS (I assume you have authenticated user and we'll use users session as JS <-> server secure channel, if not you will have to incorporate some other js auth mechanism maybe one time pass or something but it will be easy because it is your system). And voila. Only security consideration is to not allow anyone to call your servers proxy site :)